# How should I apply brick to interior wall?

Tags: drywall, brick, interior, masonry

I came across this question and I was wondering what ended up happening,real brick or brick veneer?

I want to lay the brick over drywall on one of the walls(13x10feet)in the basement. I just wanted to see if you have done yours without any complications

[How should I apply brick to an interior wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20406/how-should-i-apply-brick-to-an-interior-wall/20421#20421)

Answer (score 0):

Drywall is a bad substrate for essentially gluing heavy stuff to. It's soft weak gypsum with a facer of laminated paper that can peel right off. If you really want a brick wall inside, I'd recommend just building it right in front of the drywall. Obviously, the sanity of this idea depends on several factors, one of which is the subfloor. If you're on a concrete slab, then no sweat. Doing this on the second floor or above a basement is another story.

If that's not an option, you could probably remove the drywall and replace it with cementboard, and then mortar a thin brick veneer to it like in that other answer.